# parsing and string substring at the same time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I have this line in my html

```
<td colspan="6" align="right" id="timer"><span>Timer : 50 <span></td>
```

I am intending to rewrite it into Timer : 60, str.substring to extract only the number 60 (and removing the "Timer : "), then parsing the 60 into a var Countdown (in Jquery)

My Jquery at the moment is

```
$("#timer").html("Timer : 60")
var str = ("#timer");
var strNum = str.substring(8);
var Countdown = parseInt($("StrNum"));
```

As you can see I am doing this in seperate steps (but I am not sure if I am correct here too, I am new to these). My question is, am I doing this right, and if is there a way to combine the str.substring and parsing into a single step? Thanks

Comment: That doesn't make sense? `str` doesn't contain any numbers, nor does it have 8 characters, and you don't seem to have a `<StrNum>` element ?

Comment: I am intending to store 'Timer : 60' into the str variable in that 2nd line

then on the 3rd line, i am intending to use 'str.substring(8) to remove the 'Timer : 60' part and store the 60 into the strNum variable.

I am not sure if these make sense myself, hence my questions...Do you have any suggestion on how I should do it?

Comment: each line of your _JQuery_ code (better known as javascript) has an error, my advice for you is to get a couple hours to read some docs

Answer (score 0):

You should read the basics of jquery. For example this line

```
var str = ("#timer");
```

Does absolutely nothing, and so the rest of your script... it should look something like this

```
var str = $("#timer span").html();
var strNum = str.substr(str.length - 3, 2);
var countdown = parseInt(strNum);
```

that should work, but you really should read about [jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) and [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)

Comment: I think it should be `span` instead of `spane`, I would also parse the result of a split with `:` since the number length could change, but this also could be wrong since I have my doubts about the html from the question being valid

Comment: @FelipePereira right about the `span` tag, edited. And yes, you can use `split` and `trim`, notice also that I use `substr` instead of `substring`, is a matter of taste I guess :)